# Joining threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, join, pthreads

I have a doubt about a third party library which is essentially a wrapper around pthread.
This is how its join function is implemented:

```
            bool Join() throw ()
            {
                ThreadState s;
                {
                    CCriticalSectionLock L(m_CS);
                    s = m_CurrentThreadState;
                }

                if (s == Started) {...}
            }
```

Shouldn't have the `if (s == Started) {...}` code been put inside the block where the lock is defined?

As it is, the critical section includes a variable assignment only, that being an elementary operation would not have needed it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical section ensures that reading the shared variable (`m_CurrentThreadState`) is done atomically. C++ gives no guarantee that elementary operations are atomic, although these days one could use `std::atomic` rather than a lock.

Whether or not the lock needs to be maintained for whatever logic follows that access is a question that would require careful analysis of how the threads interact. Hopefully, the library author did that analysis, and determined that it was safe to act on the value without maintaining the lock.

Answer (score 2):

The point of the critical sections is to guard the read of the `m_CurrentThreadState` field, which might be changed by other threads.

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't have the `if (s == Started) {...}` code been put inside the block where the lock is defined?

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: No, because the critical section is covering only the state of `m_CurrentThreadState`.

In this code `s` is a local stack variable, and each thread will have it's own copy (i.e. it doesn't need to be guarded).

The code blocks access to `m_CurrentThreadState` and reads it's value (into `s`). Then, it uses the value in s (which will be consistent, even if another thread modifies `m_CurrentThreadState`).

Answer (score 1):

The variable `s` is a copy of `m_CurrentThreadState`

It would appear that the function wants to hold the lock for a short amount of time, and therefore examine a copy of this state value.

It doesn't matter if the state value changes in this time, the code will execute anyway.

Comment: Thank you, but it being a POD makes no real difference here, as long as it is a distinct copy so changes to the original value elsewhere do not affect the logic after it. Incidentally, copying a POD (even a number) is not guaranteed to be atomic.